# CORs misconfigured while triggering API Gateway endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to trigger an API on AWS API Gateway from my website using AJAX. My API Gateway triggers a Lambda. I have hosted my website on S3.

My AJAX code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: api-gateway-api-endpoint-goes-here,
  data: str,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  crossDomain: true,
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'access-control-allow-origin'
  },
  success: function(msg) {
      // blah blah
  }
});
```

The lambda handler looks somewhat like this:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # call SES send-email API
    aws_ses_response = ses_client.send_email(
        Source=blah,
        Destination=blah,
        Message=blah
    )

    return {
        'response': aws_ses_response
    }
```

I already "enabled" CORS on my API end-point on API Gateway. I added `access-control-allow-origin` as one of the values in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` mappings in `Integration Response`.

I still see this error when this AJAX call is triggered:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.xxxxx.amazonaws.com/dev/my-api' from origin 'http://www.my-website.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

When I trigger the API from cURL from a terminal, it works fine.

What am I missing? Thanks.

P.S. I looked at a few similar questions here but none of the suggestions worked. So, posting here again.

--

UPDATE: after following @hephalump's suggestion, I am able to trigger my API, just that the API response does not seem to be propogating back to the website (which is hosted on S3). I see this error when I 'inspect' my website after sending my AJAX POST request:

[image]

Comment: Is your API triggering a Lambda?

Comment: @hephalump - yes

Comment: Can you post your Lambda code?

Comment: @hephalump - i just updated my question with the lambda code. Basically I am invoking AWS SES api and returning the response from that API from my lambda.

Comment: I literally answered what was effectively the same question with apparently the same issue last night and the OP seems to have deleted it.  I'll write the response again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a Lambda proxy integration with API Gateway and CORS enabled, your browser will expect CORS headers to be returned in the response. Currently you're returning the result of ses_client.send_email, which, if it is just the raw SES sendEmail raw response, is going to be something like:

```
{
    "ResponseMetadata": {
      "RequestId": "99aaaaa9-a9aa-9999-aa99-744d6b6ede3c"
    },
    "MessageId": "0100000aa0a00a0a-715e3e9e-e010-43c1-a91f-0492d75aa64c-000000"
  }
```

As we can see, that doesn't include the CORS headers, which are required by your browser.  To resolve this, first build the result of `aws_ses_response` to include both the HTTP status code and the appropriate headers, and then return the complete response to the caller. Modify your code as follows and it should work:

```
    aws_ses_response = ses_client.send_email(
        Source=blah,
        Destination=blah,
        Message=blah
    )

    const result = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            // other required headers
        },
        body: aws_ses_response
    };

    return result;
```

Additionally, notwithstanding that the configuration of your API gateway is not totally clear to me, for your request, you may be able to remove the headers and crossDomain attributes (and maybe others). In testing this on a new APIG endpoint I just made a request to the API without these and was able to get a successful response (the body of my response is the example I gave for the raw SES sendEmail response).

Comment: Now I am able to call my lambda function and am able to send an email just fine. (yeay!). However, I am not able to get a response back to my website (which is hosted on S3). I see this error in response:

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'MY-APIG-ENDPOINT' from origin 'MY-SITE' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response My-APIG-ENDPOINT with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Comment: just posted it in the reply above.

Comment: Did you remove the headers from the request?

Comment: Yes, I removed the headers and 'crossDomain' from the ajax request.. the api is called just fine.. just that my website cannot get the response back. thanks.

Comment: I just updated the original question with the screenshot of what I see from my chrome inspector..

Comment: In the response, add the content-type to the header `'content-type': 'application/json'`, right below the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: this has to be the stupidest thing I missed.. I had to "redeploy" my API after enabling CORs in API Gateway. I enabled CORs but never redeployed.. aarrgh.. thank you so much for your help, @hephalump.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error message:

> Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed

Now look at your request:

> ```
>   headers: {
>     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
>     'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
>     'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST',
>     'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'access-control-allow-origin'
>   },
> ```

You are trying to put the permissions on your request.

It would be utterly stupid if your JavaScript could give itself permission to access any service it liked. That means these headers are *nonsense*.

Since they are nonsense, they aren't in the list of acceptable headers for a cross-origin request, so the server needs to explicitly grant you permission to set them … and it doesn't.

Stop trying to set them.

`Access-Control-*` headers need to be set by **the server**.

See [Amazon's own documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) which explicitly covers this.